# 2 Time triggers - Google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-apps-script-addon

i looked at the google app script installable trigger docs online (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support) , and one of the examples shows how 2 create 2 time triggers.

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(6)
      .create();

  // Trigger every Monday at 09:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}
```

My code:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 1 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('MainFunctionDaily')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(1)
      .create();

  // Trigger every Friday at 13:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('MainFunctionWeekly')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
      .atHour(13)
      .create();
}
```

However when i try to create the triggers, i get an error:

*This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account*

Please advise

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: The documentation for add-ons was moved. In this case the new location of the below referred restriction is https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers

---

On Google Apps Scripts add-ons it's not possible to create two triggers of the same type on the same document by a function ran on behalf of the same user.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations (emphasis mine):

> **Limitations**
>   Several limitations apply to installable triggers in add-ons:
>
> Each add-on can **only have one trigger of each type**, per user, per
>   document. For instance, in a given spreadsheet, a given user can only
>   have one edit trigger, although the user could also have a form-submit
>   trigger or a time-driven trigger in the same spreadsheet.

The alternatives are

- Use different accounts to create each trigger.
- Create several add-ons one for each required trigger
- Use a regular script rather than an add-on.

Comment: I can't believe this, but by performing a simple test it seems I can't create 2 time based triggers on two different functions. They have also removed that line from the documentation, what gives?

Comment: @Pievis The documentarion for add-ons was moved. In this case the new location of the referred restriction is https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers

Comment: thank you ! There's something I don't understand though, are now all published app script GSuite add on since the marketplace was renamed ? Since triggers can't be used on unpublished scripts, doesn't it mean that the limitations applies to everything ?

Comment: @Pievis Please post that as a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Two possible issues:

1. Your triggers are contradicting each other
2. You may need to add a create function before the second trigger.

You will probably need to choose one of your triggers only but you can try this:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(6)
      .create();
}

function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every Monday at 09:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}
```